# Insert a loading gif till the inframe in my panel in firefox addon loads

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a firefox addon. I am looking to insert a loading gif before a the page in my panel loads

Here is the code of my main.js file

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
  var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./logo1.png",
    "32": "./logo1.png",
    "64": "./logo1.png"
  },
   onClick: handleChange
});



function handleChange(state) {

      var windowsService = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);

// window object representing the most recent (active) instance of Firefox
var currentWindow = windowsService.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');

// most recent (active) browser object - that's the document frame inside the chrome
var browser = currentWindow.getBrowser();

// object containing all the data about an address displayed in the browser
var uri = browser.currentURI;
var title=browser.contentDocument.title

// textual representation of the actual full URL displayed in the browser
var ur = uri.spec;


var frame_url = someurl;
      var panel = panels.Panel({
width:650,
height:400,              
contentURL: frame_url,
contentScriptFile: data.url("preloading.js"),
contentScriptWhen:"start"
});
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });

}
```

Here is my preloading.js file.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
        });
   document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('loading.gif')";
```

When i use this javacript file I get a error that **document.body is not defined**. I have tried different versions of the preloading.js file but all of them fail.

Is there any way to add a loading gif while the page in my panel loads.

Comment: Well, uhm, what are the lines with errors? :)

Comment: I can only see the error through the command line. it goes on like index_size_err=1 , domstring_size_err=2 wrong_document_err=4, heirarchy_request_err=4 and so on

Comment: Provide error message in question body, properly quoted.

Comment: I have made few changes to my preloading.js file but now i get an error that document.body is not defined